# Is the "for...of" loop slower over time with very big arrays?

Tags: typescript, wordpress, loops

I have build a program that transfers all the products from one Wordpress site to another using the Woocommerce API and typescript.

Everything works great but the process is getting slower over time and I can't figure out why. The resources on both servers and on my own PC are really free so I'm excluding any memory leaks or any other resource problem.

There are a total of 44000 products and at the beginning of the process the program would transfer 12 products/minute, while now at 18000, it only transfers 5/minute.

The process is this:

1. I have first got all the product ids from site A and placed them in an array.
2. Using a "for of" loop on that array (44000 length) and use the id to get the product info from site A and post on site B.

Because both servers seems to be OK and the process is the same for each loop, I'm thinking the loop is somehow slower the longer it runs. Should I perhaps have used the traditional loop instead, or the issue is entirely elsewhere?

Comment: May I ask why are you doing this transfer for? shouldn't a database copy and paste be the best way to dump all the data over? also seems like you might just need wp all export and all import.